# Android Studio crash after latest update

Tags: java, android, runtime, zxing

Android Studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

After updating my android studio, it keep crashing. After a log search, i found out a plugin called IntelliLang is the cause of it. But when i remove/rename this folder i cant run/compile my project as usual.

How do i reinstall this IntelliLang plugin located in 
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\IntelliLang\lib\IntelliLang.jar

Comment: What is XML file line #46 ? add some code too so that someone can assist

Comment: @RakshitNawani <nextrackdomain.nextrack.view.QrCodeFinderView
        android:id="@+id/qr_code_view_finder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/qr_code_header_bar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />